# Solving Kakuro puzzle (5x5) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

[image]

Assuming that:

```
A+B+C=24
E+F+G=11
J+K+L=22
N+O+P=14
A+E=17
B+F+J+N=26
C+G+K+O=15
L+P=13
```

How could i find a possible solution to the problem, given the constraints above, using the predicate `solve/1`?
My first attempt was below, with no result. Thanks in advance!

```
solve(L1) :-
    L1 = [A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
    A is 24-B-C,
    B is 26-F-J-N,
    C is 15-G-K-O,
    E is 11-F-G,
    E is 17-A,
    J is 22-K-L,
    N is 14-O-P,
    L is 13-P,
    write(L1).
```

Comment: Okay, is it better now?

Comment: I don't see how you would have gotten "no result" from that code. I would have expected an instantiation error. Please describe your results accurately. Try using CLPFD. For example, `A + B + C #= 24` instead of `A is 24-B-C`. The `is/2` requires that variables in the second expression all be instantiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @lurker already said in his comment, use **CLP(FD) constraints**.

In addition, I recommend:

1. instead of `solve/1`, use a **declarative name** like `solution/1`. You should describe **what** holds for a solution, so that the relation makes sense in all directions, also for example if the solution is already given and you want to validate it.
2. By convention, it makes sense to let variables that stand for **lists** end with an `s`.
3. **Separate** side-effects from pure code. In fact, **remove** side-effects altogether. Let the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) do the printing for you!

For example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solution(Ls) :-
    Ls = [A,B,C,E,F,G,J,K,L,N,O,P],
    A #= 24-B-C,
    B #= 26-F-J-N,
    C #= 15-G-K-O,
    E #= 11-F-G,
    E #= 17-A,
    J #= 22-K-L,
    N #= 14-O-P,
    L #= 13-P.
```

This already works for queries like:

```
?- solution(Ls), Ls ins 0..sup, label(Ls).
Ls = [6, 3, 15, 11, 0, 0, 9, 0, 13, 14, 0, 0] ;
Ls = [6, 3, 15, 11, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12, 13, 0, 1] ;
Ls = [6, 3, 15, 11, 0, 0, 11, 0, 11, 12, 0, 2] ;
etc.
```

I leave completing this as an easy exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I also forgot to specify that the solutions have to be between [0-9] which means the query is modified to: solution(Ls), Ls ins 0..9, label(Ls). The problem is that there can't be the same numbers in one line or column. Explain: 
The lists below shouldn't contain duplicates.
    L1 = [A,B,C]
    L2 = [E,F,G]
    L3 = [J,K,L,N]
    L4 = [N,O,P]
    L5 = [A,E]
    L6 = [B,F,J,N]
    L7 = [C,G,K,O]
    L8 = [L,P]
How could i express these restrictions?

Comment: Try the CLP(FD) constraint `all_distinct/1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please be aware of a possible mistake. The `all_distinct` predicate should guarantee the uniqueness of all rows **and** columns.